# LibreOffice - Registered IFilter is not found - Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows, search, libreoffice, ifilter, odt

I am unable to index **contents** of LibreOffice files. Files such as .odt files cannot be indexed on Windows Search.

The error says "Registered IFilter is not found"

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibreOffice supplies IFilters for 64-bit. Today I updated to 3.6.3.2 on W7_64. The update installed its filters and they did not work. I revert back to the filter from [IFilterShop](http://www.ifiltershop.com/staroffice-openoffice-ifilter.html). This one does work (need to read the readme for Vista and W7). Its free for non-commercial usage.

Answer (score 2):

You installed all the needed optional components i libreoffice installer ?
In the optional features you can select some features that doesn't came in the typical installation.

here is a quick link to a video tutorial an step by step description on [how to install LibreOffice](http://usefultutorial.com/free-stuff/249-libreoffice-a-great-free-alternative-to-microsoft-office)

Answer (score 0):

IFilters are used to convert file formats into text for searching. The trouble is that they need to be the same 'bitness' as the app that wants to load them. So if you have a 64-bit app that wants to use the IFilters you need 64-bit IFilters installed.

Have you installed 64-bit Libre Office?

Comment: Libre Office only has a 32-bit version that is compatible with 64-bit operating systems.